# Enabling apache2 modules, Invalid command 'AddModule'

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, webdav

Running Centos 5.3
I'm not sure what the problem is here. 
The module (mod_dav.c) doesn't exist, would this cause the error? How can I compile mod_dav.so ?

Did I miss something when installing apache?

Below are the steps I've done so far.

Installing apache2:

```
yum install httpd
```

httpd.conf:

```
AddModule mod_dav.c
```

Restarting apache:

```
Invalid command 'AddModule', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
LoadModule
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it but it's already there by default.  For what it's worth I don't care about the answer much anymore since I've moved to an ssh based solution instead of webdav. Apparently `AllowOverride None` can affect this but I had it set to `All`